# How to define TextStyle in a conditional statement flutter

Tags: flutter

Might be a very obvious question, but I need to add a TextStyle in a conditional statement,  but it seems to not be applying it. This is what I tried:

```
Text((() {
                    if (contract.active == true) {
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 18);
                      return 'active';
                    }
                    return 'inactive';
                  }())),
```

It is not applying the textStyle. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an immediate anonymous function there. The first parameter of Text widget expects a string and your anonymous function returns that. The TextStyle object that you've created inside the function body doesn't do anything.

You need to change your implementation to (using immediate anonymous function):

```
Text(
    (() {
       if (contract.active) {
          return "Active";
       }
       return "Inactive";
    }()),
    style: (() {
       if (contract.active) {
          return TextStyle(fontSize: 18);
       }
       return null;
    }())
),
```

But the above code looks very odd, you can simply achieve that using ternary operator:

```
Text(contract.active ? "Active" : "Inactive",
     style: active ? TextStyle(fontSize: 18) : null),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ternary operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions):

```dart
Text(
    'dummy text',
    style: contract.active == true ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red): TextStyle(color:Colors.blue), 
)
```

I added this for only `TextStyle`, you can do it for `Text` if you want.
And one thing, `contract.active` is already `bool` you don't need to check its equality, you can use `contract.active` instead of `contract.active == true`.

You can change text like this:

```dart
Text(
    contract.active ? 'active' :'inactive'
    style: contract.active ? TextStyle(fontSize: 18) : TextStyle()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to change is the text, so f.e if active show : active, and if inactive show: inactive. And then add the textstyle.